# Select and Update Using the select statement result in temp table stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_updateInward
    (@bl_num VARCHAR(30),
     @cg_type VARCHAR(10))
AS
    CREATE TABLE #temp_select
    (
        qty int,
        wght decimal(8,2),
        vol decimal(8,2) 
    )

    INSERT INTO #temp_select
        SELECT 
            CASE 
               WHEN @cg_type = 'BB' 
                  THEN SUM(ISNULL(CAST(t1.qty AS FLOAT), 0)) 
               ELSE 1 
            END AS qty,
            SUM(ISNULL(CAST(t1.wght AS FLOAT), 0)) AS wght,
            SUM(ISNULL(CAST (t1.vol AS FLOAT), 0)) AS vol
        FROM 
            godown_storage t1
        INNER JOIN 
            ccosbl t2 ON t2.id = t1.blso_id
        WHERE
            t2.bl_num = @bl_num

    UPDATE ccosblitem
    SET qty = #temp_select.quantity, 
        wght = #temp_select.weight, 
        vol = #temp_select.volume
    FROM ccosblitem t3
    INNER JOIN ccosbl t4 ON t4.id = t3.master_id 
    WHERE t4.bl_num = @bl_num

    SELECT * FROM ccosblitem
```

I need to update the `ccosblitem` from the select statement. I do it in stored procedure and create a temp table. I tried using the declare variable but it prompt error saying that 'AS' is incorrect.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

**from:**

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE sp_updateInward
(
    @bl_num VARCHAR(30),
    @cg_type VARCHAR(10)
)
AS
```

**To:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_updateInward @bl_num VARCHAR(30),@cg_type VARCHAR(10)
AS

begin
//your action here
end
```

Comment: I'm not so sure for your alter if it worked or not. But it is the way just remove () sign.

Answer (score 0):

Your update statement need changes. You are using temp table columns in SET clause without using the temp table in FROM clause. Also for joining purpose you need to have ID column in temp table and need to populate the same column in insert statement. Below are the changes to your code.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_select
    (
        id int,
        qty int,
        wght decimal(8,2),
        vol decimal(8,2) 
    )

SELECT T1.ID, case....

UPDATE ccosblitem
    SET qty = #temp_select.quantity, 
        wght = #temp_select.weight, 
        vol = #temp_select.volume
    FROM ccosblitem t3
    INNER JOIN #temp_select t4 ON t4.id = t3.master_id
```